# Subtracting floating point numbers in a loop in bash

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file with 500 lines of floating point numbers. What I want to do is take a line, and then subtract every line lower in linenumber from that line. An example nonworking script would be:

```
for i in `seq 0 499`; do
       for ((j=0; j<i; j++)); do
               a=$(awk 'NR == i' i=$i inputfile)
               b=$(awk 'NR == j' j=$j inputfile)
               echo $(awk '{c=a-b};END{print c/NR}' a=$a b=$b)
       done
done > outputfile
```

I'm not familiar with how to use awk, so any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Example:

input:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

output:

```
1
2 - 1
3 - 1
3 - 2
4 - 1
4 - 2
4 - 3
5 - 1
5 - 2
5 - 3
5 - 4
```

Except instead of integers everything is a floating point number, and the subtractions should be evaluated

Comment: Can you give an example of input and expected output?

Comment: Sorry, it is a bit confusing. I added an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you put this into a.awk

```
{
    a[NR] = $1
}
END {
    print a[1]
    for (i = 2; i <= NR; i++) 
        for (j = 1; j < i; j++) 
            print a[i]-a[j]
}
```

and run

```
awk -f a.awk foo.txt
```

You will get your desired output.

For example, if your input was

```
1.2
2.3
3.4
4.5
5.6
```

Your output would be

```
1.2
1.1
2.2
1.1
3.3
2.2
1.1
4.4
3.3
2.2
1.1
```